Obtaining central elements of $KG$ from central elements of $KH$
Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ which is not assumed to be normal. Write $T$ for a transversal of $H$ in $G$ and let $z$ be a central element of the group algebra $KH$, where $K$ is a field. It is well known that we may write $z = \sum a_K \hat{K}$, where the sum runs over the conjugacy classes of $H$. What I want to show is the following:

Let $Z = \sum_{t \in T} z^t$, where the superscript denotes conjugation. Prove that $Z \in Z(KG)$

I have seen this fact used in a specific context in a paper, where it is stated as "obvious". Of course, if $K = x^H$ is a conjugacy class of $H$, then $\bigcup_{t \in T} K^t = x^G$, by the construction of $T$.
However, when we take the class sums, we are looking at each sum individually. Thus, it could happen that $K^t \cap K \neq \emptyset$, for instance, which could, in principle, "skew" things when we try to write $Z$ as a $K$-linear combination of the conjugacy classes of $G$.
To be more precise, if $K = \{x, x^{y_1}, ..., x^{y_k}\}$, then we want to prove that the coefficients of $x^{y_it}$ is the same in $Z$ for all $t \in T$ and for all $0 \leq i \leq k$ (with $y_0 = 1$). But I don't know what to do if, say, $x^t = x$ for some $i$ and some given $t$ in $T$, as then $\hat{K} + \hat{K}^t$ could seemingly be equal to $2x + \sum_{i=1}^k x^{y_i} + \sum_{i=1}^k x^{y_it}$.
Why is this result "obvious"? How do I deal with these cases where $K \cap K^t \neq \emptyset$?
Thanks in advance!

The intersections don't matter. Let me work first in characteristic not dividing $|G|$ for simplicity. You probably know that an element of $K[G]$ is central iff it's invariant under conjugation by all $g \in G$. It follows that there is a canonical projection from $K[G]$ to its center, namely
$$K[G] \ni z \mapsto \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} z^g \in Z(K[G]).$$
This projection sends $g \in G$ to the averaged sum over the conjugacy class of $g$.
Now suppose $z \in Z(K[H])$. Then $z^h = z$ for all $h \in H$, which means that the sum over the elements $z^g$ can be organized according to the coset of $H$ that a given $g \in G$ lies in. The result is that $\{ z^g \}$ is, as a multiset, equal to $|H| \{ z^t \}$ where $t$ is any transversal, which gives that
$$\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} z^g = \frac{1}{|G/H|} \sum_{t \in G/H} z^t$$
is central. (Note that the use of $z^t$ for $t \in G/H$ is unambiguous, since the answer really only depends on the coset of $t$; in other words the above sum can be calculated using any transversal.)
I phrased this argument in a way that requires dividing by $|G|$ but this is not necessary; it is really a combinatorial statement about counting multiplicities in a multiset of terms (which are then summed over), and this combinatorial statement is true independent of $K$. The combinatorial claim is that, as a multiset, $\{ z^t \}$ is invariant under conjugation, so summing over it gives a central element.

I mostly understand your argument, and it makes it very clear that $|H| \sum_{t \in T} z^t$ is a central element. If $\operatorname{char}(K) = 0$, I'm done. But I am mostly unfamiliar with multisets (as I understand, they are sets with possible repetition) and can't really see why ${z^t \mid t \in T}$ would be invariant by conjugation as a multiset... could you perhaps elaborate a bit more on this last point?

@Gauss: we can avoid directly arguing with multisets by instead arguing as follows. The argument showing that $|H| \sum_{t \in T} z^t$ is central actually shows that it's central in the integral group algebra $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ (let's say that $z \in \mathbb{Z}[H]$; this is really a statement about sums over conjugacy classes so this is WLOG). In this group algebra there is no issue with dividing by $|H|$ (if an expression has coefficients which are divisible by $|H|$), so it follows that $\sum_{t \in T} z^t$ is central in $\mathbb{Z}[G]$. Now we can pass to any field. Do you agree?

This division by $|H|$ is just a way to talk about dividing all the multiplicities in a multiset by $|H|$, the point is really that this argument is purely combinatorial. If we take the multiset ${ z^t }$ and conjugate it by $g \in G$ we get the multiset ${ z^{gt} }$. But $gt$ is just another transversal, and the multiset ${ z^t }$ does not depend on the choice of transversal; this is why I wrote it using $t \in G/H$ above, the notational difference here is important. So ${ z^t } = { z^{gt} }$ as multisets, including multiplicities.

Ah, I see your point now. Just one final thing: I see that the argument is sort of independent of the ring, meaning we can consider it to be $\mathbb{Z}$, from which it follows that the appropriate sum is central in $\mathbb{Z}G$, fair enough. However, how do we go from there to an arbitrary element of the center of some other group algebra? I don't presume any element from another group algebra can be projected onto / considered as an element of $\mathbb{Z}G$, right? My issue is just that the specific case I'm dealing with is exactly when $\operatorname{char}(K) = p \mid |H|$...

@Gauss: over any commutative ring $R$, the center $Z(R[H])$ is a free $R$-module with basis given by sums over the conjugacy classes of $H$. So to prove the desired statement for arbitrary elements of the center we can reduce to the case of a sum over a single conjugacy class, and this case is purely combinatorial / can be handled by doing it over $\mathbb{Z}$. Yes?

Ohhhh, you are right. Thank you so much!
